# SWT 3.7.2 Browser Widget | Internet Explorer Mobile 6

Tags: swt, windows-ce, internet-explorer-6, windows-mobile-6.5

I am developing Java for Handheld Devices. I want to implement a **Browser Widget**, but Java throws an Exception:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser

Now I am not sure if the OS and the Webbrowser are not compatible with the SWT Browser Widget.

The OS I use are:

Windows CE 5.0

Windows Mobile 6.5.3

Both are using Internet Explorer Mobile 6. Yes, the Software is quite old, but SWT 3.7.2 is working fine! Only The Browser Widget does not work.

The Internet Explorer itself works too.

Are there limitations I am not aware of? Any help is appreciated, because it is a very important Project for me.

Comment: IE6 in 2018, nice.

Comment: Well that is what our company is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched the web for ARM SWT Libraries. 
http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.7.2-201202080800/

I looked up the source file. Under Widgets is no Browser Control listed. I guess they wanted to reduce the size of the jar.

Here is explained, that the SWT Jar for "Pocket PCs" is a customized version of the original swt jar.
https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-small-cup-of-swt/pocket-PC.html

I guess I can forget about the Browser Widget.